# Bootstrap CSS glyphicon doesn't display. What should I do?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

So if you look through this code, I have used a lock and user glyphicon next to the password and email entry input tab but it just doesn't seem to work. I have been trying this code from a YouTube video and everything else works totally fine - just the glyphicon doesnt work i.e. it doesn't show at all but there isn't any error either. What could be the issue? (P.S. I am using a Mac incase that could affect this)

```
 <div class = "container">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-5">
                    <h1 class = "text-center">Log-in form</h1>
                    <label class = "label control - label"> User E-mail</label>
                    <div class = "input-group">
                        <span class = "input-group-addon"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "mail" placeholder="E-mail">
                    </div>
                    <label class = "label control - label"> User Password</label>
                    <div class = "input-group">
                        <span class = "input-group-addon"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                        <input type = "password" class = "form-control" name = "pass" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class = "row">
                        <div class = "col-md-6">
                            <input type = "checkbox"> <small>Remember me</small>
  

              </div>
                <div class = "col-md-6"> 
                    <a href = "#"><p class = "text-right">Forgot Password?</p> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href = "#"><div class = "btn btn-default">LOG IN</div></a>
            <p class = "text-center">Not a member yet? <a href = "#">Sign up</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap? Glyphicons are removed from 4x

Comment: Which version of bootstrap you're using?

Comment: @j08691 version 4.5.2

Comment: Well then I guess you have your answer. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/migration/#components

Comment: @OMiShah version 4.5.2